# Python "Print Function" [HackerRank Problem]

Tags: python

Take input from the STDIN.
Without using any string, try to print the following.

123...n

Example

n = 5
Print 12345.

```
n = int(input())

total = m = 0

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    m = n - i
    total = total + (i * (10 ** m))

print(total)
```

This logic works fine up to 9, but when I take input as 10, it's not working.
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just `print(i, end="")` in the for loop instead of trying to create the entire thing first before printing it? Also, you could store `total` as a string if you do need to do it this way, and it would make it easier.

Comment: @Lecdi Thanks for your help. I checked this solution in hacker rank as well. Is there any way we can solve this problem using math? In my case, it is working up to 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in a purely math way, you can use logs to calculate the number of digits a number has. Generally, it's the ceiling of the log10 of the number, but you have to deal with the edge case for powers of 10 (e.g. 10, 100, 1000, etc.).

```
import math

n = 100

total = 0

for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i < 10:
        num_digits = 1
    else:
        num_digits = math.log10(i)
        if math.ceil(num_digits) == num_digits:
            num_digits = int(num_digits) + 1
        else:
            num_digits = math.ceil(num_digits)
    
    total *= 10**num_digits
    total += i
    
print(total)
```

Comment: Ah, right, you can just strip the digits using integer division and mod 10 and just add those one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

For each next number, "append" the right amount of zeros, then replace them with the number.

```py
n = 100

total = 0
for i in range(1, n+1):
    j = i
    while j:
        j //= 10
        total *= 10
    total += i
print(total)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3m_IUbBUMDQy4uErySxJzgBwDrrT8IoVMhcw8haLEvPRUDUMdhTxtQ00rLgUgyAKqyASzyjMyc1IVsiDCECl9fZBZcAGIiVpwMQhfG2RAQVFmXokGWEAT4hKog2AOAwA)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is also a reasonable solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a totally different way to approach this:

```
n = int(input()) # This is the Input
list_of_numbers = [] # Make an empty list
for i in range(n): # Make a for loop which iterates through 'n' and appends (n - i), so it is appending numbers from highest to lowest
    list_of_numbers.append(str(n - i))
list_of_numbers.reverse() # We reverse the descending order to ascending order
print(''.join(list_of_numbers)) # Since this is a list, simply use .join to join the elements into a string and get the desired answer
```